# "On launch" vs "at launch"

Tags: differences, prepositions, expression-choice

I've had a disagreement with a friend over the use of 'on' concerning the the launch of a certain product. He insists it should be 'at launch' while I believe either 'on launch' or 'at launch' is fine. I would greatly appreciate any light shed on this quandary.

Comment: Both are used. Offhand I can't characterize the contexts where one would be more appropriate than the other.

Answer (score 2):

While "at launch" may be more common, I do believe it should be "on launch" simply because the launch time is just that: a time. If we were to include the place I'd be more inclined to agree with your friend (such as At [Sydney's] launching).

> The game launched at Sydney on Monday.
>
> The game launched on Monday at Sydney.
>
> On the game's launch at Sydney.
>
> On launch, the game blah blahed.

At the very least you could use either.

Answer (score 1):

If it is being used for the launch of a product, "at launch" seems (after some **very** basic research...) to be more usual, with a meaning of "at [the time of] launch", as in these examples:

*[At launch, Sky Q will not have any 4K content available for customers](http://www.pocket-lint.com/news/135971-sky-explains-why-sky-q-won-t-get-4k-at-launch)*

*[All 104 Xbox 360 Games Available At Launch Revealed](http://www.ibtimes.com/xbox-one-backwards-compatibility-all-104-xbox-360-games-available-launch-revealed-2176061)*

*[games that are broken at launch seem to be a regular occurrence](http://gamerant.com/broken-games-launch-batman-halo-diablo-155/)*

"On launch" seems to be used with a sense of "on starting", describing an action or event rather than a time:

*[Photoshop CC 2015 crashes on launch](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/photoshop-crash-with-faulty-module-photoshop-exe.html)*

*[Antares Rocket Explodes On Launch](http://digg.com/video/antares-explosion-video)*

Of course, this leaves a very large grey area.